# A Expected Declaration Error when trying to assign a text to label

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a label class which contain other labels.

here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        class mainLabel: UILabel{
            var top: UILabel! = UILabel()
            top.text = "text" //*Expected declaration error
            var down: UILabel! = UILabel()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdzE4EtBZaM

Comment: There are several issues with your code. The error you receive is because you can only declare variables or functions in a class scope and using `top.text` you're trying to modify an instance property of the class outside the function scope, which is not allowed.

Secondly, you shouldn't declare a class inside a function that rarely makes sense. Lastly, don't declare anything as an implicitly unwrapped optional (`UILabel!`) if you're assigning a value to it right away. Without more context it's hard to grasp what are you trying to achieve using, so it's hard to give an answer with code.

Comment: I'm trying to create a pre made object of multiple labels.
So I can reuse it whenever I call it.
Am I on the right track?
I'm trying to create a label by code instead of dragging it in from the Object Library basically.

Comment: Can anyone do an example for me. I'm clueless of what to do, and don't even know the term to search for the solution.

Comment: The main challenge in that case will be handling the layout. You can either add Autolayout constraints programatically or add your `UILabel`s to a stackview.

Comment: Yes, that is one step further to my goal.
But right now I can't even assign text to my label.
Am I right about using class? to reuse object that is.

Comment: Yes you're right about using a class, but I'd suggest subclassing `UIStackView` or `UIView` rather than `UILabel`. I've created a `UIStackView` subclass for demonstrating how to achieve your goals, have a look at my answer.

Comment: thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. The error you receive is because you can only declare variables or functions in a class scope and using `top.text` you're trying to modify an instance property of the class outside the function scope, which is not allowed.

Secondly, you shouldn't declare a class inside a function that rarely makes sense.

Lastly, don't declare anything as an implicitly unwrapped optional (`UILabel!`) if you're assigning a value to it right away.

There are several ways to create a reusable UI element that consists of 2 `UILabel` and can be created programatically. You can subclass a `UIStackView` to handle the layout automatically or if you want more control, you could simply subclass `UIView`, add the 2 `UILabel`s as `subView`s and handle the layout by adding Autolayout constraints programatically.

Here's a solution using a `UIStackView` subclass. Modify any properties to fit your exact needs, this is just for demonstration.

```
class MainLabel: UIStackView {
    let topLabel = UILabel()
    let bottomLabel = UILabel()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        axis = .vertical
        distribution = .fillEqually
        addArrangedSubview(topLabel)
        addArrangedSubview(bottomLabel)
        topLabel.textColor = .orange
        topLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        bottomLabel.textColor = .orange
        bottomLabel.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Test in a Playground:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
let mainLabel = MainLabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mainLabel
mainLabel.topLabel.text = "Top"
mainLabel.bottomLabel.text = "Bottom"
```